# Program tries to access to an invalid index after I modify it

Tags: netlogo

I start modifying the Voronoi model in the model library and I tried to also make the program to show the [Delaunay Triangulation](http://modelingcommons.org/browse/one_model/5279#model_tabs_browse_procedures)! However I get errors because the program tries to access to indexes bigger than the size the list I have.

This is the part I replace

```
 ca
  set numpoints 20; adjust if interface expanded to include more points
  let xlist (list 0 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 x11 x12 x13 x14 x15 x16   x17 x18 x19 x20)
  let ylist (list 0 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8 y9 y10 y11 y12 y13 y14 y15 y16 y17 y18 y19 y20)
  let vallist (list 0 val1 val2 val3 val4 val5 val6 val7 val8 val9 val10 val11 val12 val13 val14 val15 val16 val17 val18 val19 val20)
  let onlist (list false point1 point2 point3 point4 point5 point6 point7 point8 point9 point10 point11 point12 point13 point14 point15 point16 point17 point18 point19 point20)
```

In the [Voronoi program](http://modelingcommons.org/browse/one_model/1210#model_tabs_browse_procedures), I tried the following code:

```
  set numpoints number
  set onlist (list points)
  set xlist [xcor] of points
 set ylist [ycor] of points
 set vallist [value] of points

  set onlist fput false onlist
  set xlist fput 0 xlist
  set ylist fput 0 ylist
  set vallist fput 0 vallist
  clear-drawing
```

But this fails and in a catastrophic. Look
[The program failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cZtt.png)

I spend like 3 or 4 hours tried to solve this problem. Why does this happens.

Comment: Here is the complete code. [Github] (https://github.com/MariaG02/Tf/blob/master/Simulacion%20Red.nlogo)

Answer (score 1):

I think this specific error stems from this code:

```
  create-points numpoints + 1 [ if who != 0 [set shape "circle" set size .6 set color red]
                      setxy item who xlist item who ylist
                      set value item who vallist
                      set label who set label-color black
                      set hidden? not item who onlist
                      set super? false
                      face patch 0 0
  ]
```

You have already created your lists based on the current points that exist, which have `who` values from zero to the number of turtles. Then you create more points, which have `who` values beyond the number of entries in your `xlist`, `vallist`, etc.

For example, say you clear everything and create 3 turtles. They will have `who` values of 0, 1, and 2. If you create the `xlist` of those turtles, it will create a list that is 3 entries long. Now, if you run your `create-points numpoints...` code, you will start creating new turtles. The first turtle that is created will have a `who` value of 3. Now, if that turtle tries to access `item who xlist`, it will be trying to get the item with the index of 3, but the list only has index values 0, 1, and 2.

**Edit**

```
to generaRed

  set numpoints number
  set onlist (list points)
  set xlist [xcor] of points
  set ylist [ycor] of points
  set vallist [value] of points

  set onlist fput false onlist
  set xlist fput 0 xlist
  set ylist fput 0 ylist
  set vallist fput 0 vallist
  clear-drawing

  if max xlist > max-pxcor - 1 or max ylist > max-pycor - 1 or min xlist < min-pxcor + 1 or min ylist < min-pycor + 1
     [user-message "One or more coordinate values are outside the screen range.  Please check your inputs and setup again"
      stop]

  ask points [ die ]

  ( foreach xlist ylist vallist [
    [ x y v ] ->
    create-points 1 [
      setxy x y
      set value v
      set super? false
      set hidden? false
      face patch 0 0
      set size 10
    ]
    ]
    )
  ask points with [not hidden?] [if distance min-one-of other points with [not hidden?] [distance myself] = 0
    [user-message "Two or more active points have identical coordinates.  Please halt, revise your inputs and setup again" stop]]
  create-points 1 [set hidden? true set super? true setxy (min-pxcor + 1) (min-pycor + 1)] ; who numpoints + 1
  create-points 1 [set hidden? true set super? true setxy (min-pxcor + 1) (max-pycor - 1)] ; who numpoints + 2
  create-points 1 [set hidden? true set super? true setxy (max-pxcor - 1) (max-pycor - 1)] ; who numpoints + 3
  create-points 1 [set hidden? true set super? true setxy (max-pxcor - 1) (min-pycor + 1)] ; who numpoints + 4
end
```

Comment: I see, but how  I solve this, i was thinking that then i should do

Comment: But, how I solve this?  `ask points[die]` give me the same error. I gues I could change `create points numpoints + 1`  with `ask points` and then create a point whit value 0 and false. Would this work?

Comment: @MariaGuthier - In general, using `who` for things like this is discouraged for reasons like the problem you're finding. I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, so it's hard to offer advice. See my edits for a modified `generaRed` that doesn't *usually* throw errors if your run `setup` then `generaRed`, but again I'm not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Just generated the Delaunay triangulation, this is going to be the base for simulations of a transport network

Comment: @MariaGuthier - I think you may need to break down your questions into small discrete components to get more useful answers- consider the [asking help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically the section on making an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In general- if you can provide code that demonstrates your problem that is easy for users to copy and paste into a new NetLogo instance you will be more likely to have your issue addressed.

Comment: I see, the problem is that i dont know what is broken. thank you.